# FormControl In FormArray with property Names

Tags: angular

I have a Form with formArray

```
let myForm=formBuilder.group({
   "firstName":[],
   "subjects":formBuilder.array([])
})
```

//For Adding New Control:-

```
(<FormArray>self.myForm.controls['subjects']).push(new FormControl());
```

//For Rendering Form:-

```
<div *ngFor="let control in myForm.controls['subjects'].controls;let i=index">
     <input formControlName="{{i}}"
<div>
```

When I submit the form I get the value Object as:
{
"firstName":"abc",
"subjects":["a","b"]
}

Can I make the FormControl in FormArray such way that I can get object for subjects???

Answer (score 0):

The value of your form resembles the object structure that you create with your FormGroups, FormArrays and FormControls. So, if you want your subject to be an object, you have to ensure that you bind your 'subject' to a form group, and then have form controls for each property of that 'subject' form group.

Eg, if you want your subject to look like: `{ a: 'some value', b: 'some other value }`, then:

```
<div *ngFor="let control in myForm.controls['subjects'].controls;let i=index">
     <div [formGroup]="control">
         <input formControlName="a" />
         <input formControlName="b"
     </div>
<div>
```

This of course means that when you push a new control onto your subject FormControlArray, you have to ensure you add the same FormGroup structure, rather than a single FormControl

**Edit:**

Since your subject is a dynamic object, meaning that you don't know what the properties are, then you can't use formControlName="a" since in that example, 'a' is a fixed string.

However, you can instead bind to variables, so you can do something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let control in myForm.controls['subjects'].controls;let i=index">
     <div [formGroup]="control">
         <input [formControlName]="firstProperty" />
         <input [formControlName]="secondProperty"
     </div>
<div>
```

where `firstProperty` and `secondProperty` are member variables in your component containing strings. Then if `firstProperty = "x"` and `secondProperty="y"`,  you'll end up with a subject of `{ x: 'input value', y: 'other input value' }`.

With that ability, you can get creative and have your different property names stored in an array for example that you can index into. And that way, you get your dynamic objects.

eg.

**In your component,**

```
subjectFields = [
  { prop1: 'math', prop2: 'science' },
  { prop1: 'bio', prop2: 'chem' },
  ....
]
```

**And then your template,**

```
<div *ngFor="let control in myForm.controls['subjects'].controls;let i=index">
     <div [formGroup]="control">
         <input [formControlName]="subjectFields[i].prop1" />
         <input formControlName="subjectFields[i].prop1" />
         ......
     </div>
<div>
```

And you'll end up with your first subject being `{ math: 'input val', science: 'input val 2' }` and the second being `{ bio: 'input val', chem: 'input val' }` etc.

Comment: This works if we have the object property defined.In my case subject could be anything.eg
{"math":2,"science":4}  or {"physics":5,"computer":6}
It will depend on the control type.